# Object data source select method returning nothing in code call

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, webforms

I have an `ObjectDataSource` with the proper `SelectMethod` and `SelectParameters` configured. The data source is bound to a grid view which successfully displays the data on page load.

What I need is the ability to rerun the `Select` method defined by the `ObjectDataSource` to be stored in a variable and manipulate the items in it. The issue I keep encountering is that calling the `.Select()` method always returns 0 rows despite it populating the grid view properly.

Is there a reason I can't manually rerun the `Select()` method on the object data source?

### Update 2:

Here is how I setup the `ObjectDataSource`:

```
myObjectDataSource.TypeName = typeof(MyDataAccessObject).ToString();
myObjectDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetBy" + stringVariable;
myObjectDataSource.SelectCountMethod = "GetCountBy" + stringVariable;
myObjectDataSource.EnablePaging = true;
```

### Update 1:

I run the `Select()` on a link button's `OnClick` event:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetupDataSource(); // populates the objSource's SelectMethod, SelectParameters and TypeName etc.
    var items = objSource.Select();
    int count = items.Count(); // returns 0;
}
```

The ObjectDataSource is setup (SelectMethod and SelectParameters are set) in the `Page_Load` event.

`ObjectDataSource` definition:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objSource" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" SortParameterName="sortExpression" ></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

`GridView` definition:

```
        <asp:GridView 
        ID="myGridView" 
        runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="objSource"
        AllowPaging="true"
        ShowHeader="true" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowSorting="true" 
        Width="100%" >
```

Comment: I just did this with no problem in a simple app.  Can you post some sample code?

Comment: I've did also. No problems found. I think you do something wrong in SetupDataSource()

Comment: Can you post up your `SetupDataSource()` function so that we can help you further?

Comment: Updated with `SetupDataSource()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that underlying data access object's method took pagination into account and was returning `.Take(maximumRows)` which was always 0.

As a workaround, I programmatically disabled pagination via `myObjectDataSource.EnablePaging = false;` then created a new function which does not take into account pagination (a new function was required because the `ObjectDataSource` was looking for a function with specific paremeters).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention when (in what event you are trying to rebind the to the DataSource)
Short code snippet may help.

If you are in Postback then Gridviews are not re-bound on postback, their rows are pulled back from viewstate. Resetting the gridview's DatasourceID to the object data source ID on page load (or init?) will cause the gridview to be rebound.

Comment: I'm not trying to rebind to the data source. I want to use the data source to rerun the select but store the results in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem before. I think .Select() is implemented using DataReader and once Select has been called once the reader is empty so any subsequent call to .Select or .Count() will return empty result.

Therefore, what you can do is to use .ToList() to store the result in a list and then just keep reusing the list.

Comment: I can't store it in a list b/c queries sometimes return 300k+ rows.

Comment: Excuse the last comment, I meant that I don't want to `always` store it in a variable because I don't always need it stored in a variable (only need it when a user clicks a button on the website).